# How to calculate F-statistic from a svyglm model in R

Tags: r, survey, weighted-regression

I am struggling to figure out the correct way to calculate the F-statistic of a regression model that uses complex survey data in R. I am using svyglm from the R survey package.

Would the below code correctly calculate the F-statistic for a svyglm object?

```
library(survey)

data(api)

dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

model <- svyglm(api00~ell+meals+mobility, design=dstrat)


  #Sum of Squares Error 
  SSE <- model$deviance
  #Regression Sum of Squares 
  SSR <- model$null.deviance - SSE
  #Degrees of Freedom SSR (number of parameters or coefficients)
  df_SSR <- length(coefficients(model)) - 1
  #DF for error (# of PSU - # of Strata - # Predictors)
  df_SSE <- model$df.residual
  #Total sum of squares
  TSS <- ESS + RSS
  #F Statistic
  F_statistic <- (SSR/df_SSR)/(SSE/df_SSE)
```

I was also wondering if this is something that can instead be done using the anova.svyglm command by running the model in question against a null model?

Thank you for assistance as I am just learning about analyzing complex survey data and the nuances it involves.